# KRAKEND - context deadline exceeded

Tags: http-post, krakend

When performing load testing by hitting an API with Krakend endpoint with TPS upto 3000, we are continuously getting the below error:
[KRAKEND] 2023/07/12 - 12:33:03.383 ▶ ERROR [ENDPOINT: /v1/sms/send] context deadline exceeded

All the requests are failing with 500 Internal Server Error. Can anyone tell why this error comes and what all to take care to prevent this.

I'm expecting the requests go through as the application is capable to handle 3000 TPS.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend is reaching a timeout. So it's not performant enough. Raise the timeout or use a proper backend for testing.